# How to obtain count information for all variables in a dataframe for each column in in that dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe where every column is a different group and each value in that column is some sort of identifier. All the columns are different lengths and there is some overlap in the values between groups. My goal is to produce a new dataframe in which the columns names have remained the same, every value that was present in the initial dataframe is listed as a row name, and there is count data for each of those values contained within each corresponding cells.

Input DF:

```
A         B         C         D                                                                                             
Lamp      Car       Orange    Apple   
Potato    Car       Work      Run  
Computer  Sword     Run        
Buns                Tab
Screen
Drain
```

DF I would like to obtain, or some semblance of this :

```
           A         B         C         D                                                                                             
Lamp       1         0         0         0
Potato     1         0         0         0
Computer   1         0         0         0
Buns       1         0         0         0
Screen     1         0         0         0
Drain      1         0         0         0
Car        0         2         0         0
Sword      0         1         0         0
Orange     0         0         1         0
Work       0         0         1         0
Run        0         0         1         1
Tab        0         0         1         0
Apple      0         0         0         1
```

I have tried to do some looking around at similar posts, but I have not been able to find something quite suitable. Any help in doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you put your data in two columns, one for the current column names and one for the values, you should be able to use `table` to get the values you want. You could use `tidyr::pivot_longer` to get the two columns if needed.

Comment: You cannot have a `data.frame` where columns have different lengths. Depending on how you are getting your data it will either fail or fill them with NAs.

Comment: Can you provide your data in a reproducible format using `dput` or similar? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tidyverse approach. First, reshape to a long df and aggregate the groups. Then, reshape the variables back to a wide df.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  drop_na(value) %>% 
  count(name, value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(value, names_from = name, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)

# # A tibble: 13 x 5
#    value        A     B     C     D
#    <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1 Buns         1     0     0     0
#  2 Computer     1     0     0     0
#  3 Drain        1     0     0     0
#  4 Lamp         1     0     0     0
#  5 Potato       1     0     0     0
#  6 Screen       1     0     0     0
#  7 Car          0     2     0     0
#  8 Sword        0     1     0     0
#  9 Orange       0     0     1     0
# 10 Run          0     0     1     1
# 11 Tab          0     0     1     0
# 12 Work         0     0     1     0
# 13 Apple        0     0     0     1
```

The dataset:

```
dat <- structure(list(A = c("Lamp", "Potato", "Computer", "Buns", "Screen", 
"Drain"), B = c("Car", "Car", "Sword", NA, NA, NA), C = c("Orange", 
"Work", "Run", "Tab", NA, NA), D = c("Apple", "Run", NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This solved my issue and was extremely helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution:

```r
# turn into a list of non-NA characters
dat <- lapply(dat, na.omit)

# get the common levels
lvls <- unique(unlist(dat))

# use table on each of them 
sapply(dat, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = lvls)))
#R>          A B C D
#R> Lamp     1 0 0 0
#R> Potato   1 0 0 0
#R> Computer 1 0 0 0
#R> Buns     1 0 0 0
#R> Screen   1 0 0 0
#R> Drain    1 0 0 0
#R> Car      0 2 0 0
#R> Sword    0 1 0 0
#R> Orange   0 0 1 0
#R> Work     0 0 1 0
#R> Run      0 0 1 1
#R> Tab      0 0 1 0
#R> Apple    0 0 0 1
```

Alternatively, you can avoid assigning variables as follows:

```r
sapply(dat, function(x, lvls) table(factor(x, lvls)),
       lvls = unique(unlist(dat)))
#R>          A B C D
#R> Lamp     1 0 0 0
#R> Potato   1 0 0 0
#R> Computer 1 0 0 0
#R> Buns     1 0 0 0
#R> Screen   1 0 0 0
#R> Drain    1 0 0 0
#R> Car      0 2 0 0
#R> Sword    0 1 0 0
#R> Orange   0 0 1 0
#R> Work     0 0 1 0
#R> Run      0 0 1 1
#R> Tab      0 0 1 0
#R> Apple    0 0 0 1
```

Or the perhaps more efficient version from R 4.1.0 or greater:

```r
dat |> lapply(na.omit) |>
  (\(z) sapply(z, function(x, lvls) table(factor(x, lvls)),
               lvls = unique(unlist(z))))() 
#R>          A B C D
#R> Lamp     1 0 0 0
#R> Potato   1 0 0 0
#R> Computer 1 0 0 0
#R> Buns     1 0 0 0
#R> Screen   1 0 0 0
#R> Drain    1 0 0 0
#R> Car      0 2 0 0
#R> Sword    0 1 0 0
#R> Orange   0 0 1 0
#R> Work     0 0 1 0
#R> Run      0 0 1 1
#R> Tab      0 0 1 0
#R> Apple    0 0 0 1
```

`dat` is defined as follows:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  A = c("Lamp", "Potato", "Computer", "Buns", "Screen", "Drain"), 
  B = c("Car", "Car", "Sword", NA, NA, NA), 
  C = c("Orange", "Work", "Run", "Tab", NA, NA), 
  D = c("Apple", "Run", NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd give this a shot in `base`. There's probably room for improvement here...

```
dat <- structure(list(
  A = c("Lamp", "Potato", "Computer", "Buns", "Screen", "Drain"),
  B = c("Car", "Car", "Sword", NA, NA, NA),
  C = c("Orange", "Work", "Run", "Tab", NA, NA), 
  D = c("Apple", "Run", NA, NA, NA, NA)),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -6L))

# get unique values
levels = unique(as.vector(as.matrix(dat)))

# coerce dat fields to factor format
dat <- lapply(dat, factor, levels = levels)

# get frequency of factor levels
freq <- lapply(dat, table)

# unlist and rotate
t(do.call(rbind, freq))
```